# How to copy a file to a path with a space in it in Bash Script?

Tags: bash, shell-script

Sample script to copy `/tmp/template.txt` file to any directory as specified in `$1`.

copy_script.sh

```
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    echo No Argument
    echo "Usage: $0 <path>"
else
    cp /tmp/template.txt $1
fi
```

Before

```
wolf@linux:~$ ls -lh
total 4.0K
drwxrwxr-x 2 wolf wolf 4.0K Dis  31 10:08 'another directory'
wolf@linux:~$
```

Testing script

```
wolf@linux:~$ copy_script.sh 
No Argument
Usage: /home/wolf/bin/copy_script.sh <path>
wolf@linux:~$
```

Testing code with current path

```
wolf@linux:~$ copy_script.sh .
```

After (it works)

```
wolf@linux:~$ ls -lh
total 8.0K
drwxrwxr-x 2 wolf wolf 4.0K Dis  31 10:08 'another directory'
-rw-rw-r-- 1 wolf wolf   12 Dis  31 10:26  template.txt
wolf@linux:~$
```

Then, I test with another directory which has space in it.

This time, it doesn't work anymore even though the directory has been put it quote (both single/double quote doesn't work).

```
wolf@linux:~$ copy_script.sh 'another directory'
cp: target 'directory' is not a directory
wolf@linux:~$ 
wolf@linux:~$ ls -lh another\ directory/
total 0
wolf@linux:~$
```

How do I make this work with directory name with space in it?

Comment: Quote your parameter expansion: `"$1"`. See for example [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary)

Comment: [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) is good at pointing out common mistakes like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment above, always quote your parameter expansion.

```
cp /tmp/template.txt "$1"
```

You can read more about it here.

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html
https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe

Full code

```
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    echo No Argument
    echo "Usage: $0 <path>"
else
    cp /tmp/template.txt "$1"
fi
```

This should fix your issue with whitespace.

You also might want to check `shellcheck` script. It's very useful to identify issue like this.

```
$ shellcheck script.sh 

In script.sh line 1:
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
^-- SC2148: Tips depend on target shell and yours is unknown. Add a shebang.


In script.sh line 5:
    cp /tmp/template.txt $1
                         ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Did you mean: 
    cp /tmp/template.txt "$1"

For more information:
  https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2148 -- Tips depend on target shell and y...
  https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2086 -- Double quote to prevent globbing ...
$
```